# 2.8 - Do I still need to mark each animation action for saving?

Tags: animation, dopesheet, actions

In Blender 2.8, do I still need to mark each animation action for saving, or will it retain the animation action datablocks when I close Blender down?

I'm sorta used to having to doing some extra clicks in 2.7 etc in order to preserve my animation actions, so that they're retained when Blender shuts down.

After some tests with 2.8, it appears that the animation datablocks are being saved by default, but I'd really like to get confirmation on this from the horses mouth - or from users used to using this feature.

Comment: I think work has been done to ensure Blender does a better job at keeping user created information but not everything made it to 2.80. Not sure what was implemented already or which parts will come later. There are plans to eventually drop fake users completely, but as far as I know it is not yet in place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, did a little extra checking on the Blender Artists forums and it seems that, for the moment at least, Fake User is still required.

thedaemon:

> I’m still going to turn on Fake User because of the loss of animations
>   before they fixed it. I don’t honestly know, I ran a test and it seems
>   to save, but that was a quick test.

zeauro:

> Actions saving requires a user. If action is used by an animated
>   object when Save operator is called : action is saved. If action is
>   removed from object that is no more animated when Save operator is
>   called, it appears with a 0 next to its name in actions list : action
>   will be lost. If action has a fake user, you pressed shield icon
>   before removing it from object that is no more animated when Save
>   operator is called, it appears with an F next to its name in actions
>   list : action is saved.